# Mayavi has stopped working, crashes Python Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, vtk, mayavi

I had installed Mayavi package in Anaconda Python on my Windows 7 machine. It was working until today. Today, it has stopped working, and crashes my Python Jupyter notebook. For example, the following simple script causes "Python has stopped working" message and Python kernel death:

```
import numpy as np
import mayavi
from mayavi import mlab
x, y, z = np.ogrid[-10:10:20j, -10:10:20j, -10:10:20j]
s = np.sin(x*y*z)/(x*y*z)
sf = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(s)
```

The versions of Anaconda, Python, and Mayavi are 4.1.1, 3.5.2, and 4.5. Additionally the versions of numpy, traits, and vtk (required packages for Mayavi) 1.11.1, 4.6, and 7.0.0. I tried updating Mayavi and all these packages, and that did not resolve the issue. Can someone please help?

Comment: Hi, there is not much to guess from your question. Was the change related to an update of any of the Python stack? (interpreter, jupyter, numpy, mayavi, vtk)? How did you try to update?

Comment: Issue resolved. Writing my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the issue is that Mayavi display does not work over a remote desktop connection, which is what I was working through yesterday! I have not clue why, and am curious to know if someone has an answer. I'm logged into the machine directly today, and it works.

Comment: By default, mayavi only works locally as it opens an X connection. It might be possible to setup the offscreen rendering mode to avoid the problem, see http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/tips.html
The notebook mode is quite recent, so there is not a lot of information online yet about this type of problem.